# Visual Studio development server - setting start page to allow dynamic port allocation

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, developing and debugging a ASP.NET C# application.

(I would imagine that other versions of Visual Studio might also have this issue, hence the additional tags.)

During debugging I find it easier to set the Start URL (in the project's Properties tab) to

```
http://localhost:[port]/Account/Login
```

where [port] is the port that the development server opens when it is created.

This [port], however, is the issue; as the development server can potentially not work/stop working from time to time, and can occasionally re-assign to a different localhost port, setting the start page as above - basically a static address - means extra work having to either alter the URL in the debugging browser window, or going into the properties page of the solution and changing the port number prior to debugging.

Admittedly, its not *much* extra work, and it might be a case of laziness, but its not really necessary when there might be potential for a dynamic alternative that I'm not aware of. The use of visual studio's built-in development server is preferred over setting up a dedicated static server simply for speed of setting up a project and for brief stints of development debugging of new code additions.

In an ideal world and/or for longer QA debugging, I'd publish to a dedicated debug server, but that would be for a nearly finished project in its entirety or major milestones.

Is there any way of setting a relative/dynamic port as part of the start page in a solution's properties page, or will I just have to keep changing the port manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to scope the ports VS/IIS Express will use for running the dev server. I have never heard of a work around of killing the dev server when it locks up - I just close/stop the server from the toolbar.

The dev server should only lock up occasionally. If it's frequent then I would look into other causes or what you were referring to and stand up a full blown dev IIS server, but like you said, that takes a bit more time.

Comment: Well, that is a bit disappointing. Until Microsoft design some flexibility into Visual Studio regarding this I'll just have to keep doing it manually. Thanks for the response.